# How to use dplyr in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

Hello I am just getting started using Sparklyr and I am getting an error when trying to use dplyr to wrangle some data.

```
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

spark_read_csv(sc, "df2_tbl", 
"C:/Users/...csv")

 spark_read_csv(sc, "df_n2_tbl", 
"C:/Users/...csv")
```

I see the objects "df2_tbl" and "df2_n2_tbl" in the "Connections" tab next to "Environment" and "History" as well as on the Spark UI, but when I run the following

```
match_cat <- df_n2_tbl %>% 
         filter(var1 %in% df2_tbl) %>% 
         collect()
```

I get the error -

```
"Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'df_n2_tbl' not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to assign the results of the spark_read_csv() function to an object.

```
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

df1 <- spark_read_csv(sc, "df2_tbl", 
"C:/Users/...csv")

df2 <- spark_read_csv(sc, "df_n2_tbl", 
"C:/Users/...csv")
```